# Default Apache index page parameters

Tags: apache, ubuntu, indexing, directoryindex

I was very surprised that I couldn't find this answer on Google.

I have seen someone access the default Apache index page (no index.html present, so it just shows the directory listing) with query string parameters. The URL they used was similar to:

```
http://example.com/?C=M;O=D
```

It looks like `O=D` means "order = descending," since it reversed the order of the list, but I want to know what other parameters can be passed in, and what they mean. Is this documented somewhere? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [http://www.gforums.net](http://www.gforums.net/web-design-coding-programming-forum/7234-what-does-c-m-o-d-mean.html)

"C=M;O=D" is the query string passed in to the URLs that are browseable. It's used to sort the files list.

O is the sort order, which can either be A or D for ascending and descending respectively.

C is for column name which is to be sorted. It can take the following values:

N - Name (file name) column

M - Last Modified column

S - Size column

D - might be for Description

You might want to have a look at this : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: Thanks. The Apache docs page explains it completely. Not sure how I didn't find that in my searches.